# Spotipy - track names and energy values

Tags: python, list, spotipy

```
def lowEnergy():

    tids = []
    # get songs by recommendation
    results = sp.recommendations(seed_artists = [artist['id']])

    #retrieve uris for songs
    for track in results['tracks']:
        tids.append(track['uri'])

    #get audio_features
    features = sp.audio_features(tids)

    #pick energies
    energy = [x['energy'] for x in features]

    #here I filter out low energy values
    low_energy = [x for x in energy if x < 0.5]

    #get track names
    track_names = [sp.track(uri)['name'] for uri in tids]
```

Now I would like to **filter out track names by energy values below 0.5**, like so:

`track name1 - 0.49
 track name2 - 0.34`

and so on.

but I'm struggling here...how do I achieve this? thanks

Comment: Could you post errors or data outputs if any.

Comment: @Jclarke there are no erros. all lists print the right data. the problem is achieving a list to link all others as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but hope it works.

```
for i, e in enumerate(energy):
    if e < 0.5:
        track_name = sp.track(tids[i])['name']
        print("{} - {}".format(track_name, e))
```